# Why the child objects gets vanish when we pass reference to its __proto__ property?

Tags: javascript, vscode-debugger

```js
// Same code on Code Snippet By StackOverflow
let Teacher = function (tn) {
    this.tN = tn;
};
let PhTeacher = function (msub) {
    this.mSub = msub;
}


let objectOfPhT = new PhTeacher("Phsyics");
objectOfPhT.__proto__ = new Teacher("Aslam");
console.log(objectOfPhT)
```

SO code snippet output

```
{
  "mSub": "Phsyics",
  "tN": "Aslam"
}
```

VS code output:

```
Teacher { mSub: 'Phsyics' }
```

Comment: What do you mean with *child objects vanish*? The snippet output surely is correct. VS Code probably just shows less properties to make the output readable even with many inherited properties.

Comment: Why the result of vscode does not have "tN": "Aslam"

Comment: Also notice that `__proto__` property is being deprecated and its use is discouraged.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @Luca De Nardi Thanks. This link helped me.